# Shopify checkout customization vs Magento Enterprise

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, magento, shopify

I am a non-technical ecommerce manager. I'm looking for opinions from developers who have worked with both Magento and Shopify specifically to compare and contrast.

I'm intimately familiar with Magento Enterprise, having operated a store for 2 years with 15000 skus in about $$M revenue. My experience was working with a partner which provided about 10-40 hours of development work per week. I found licencing fee manageable but would always rather spend money on dev work then licencing.

**Magento perception**

- Powerful and flexible enough to do whatever I wanted.
- Steep learning curve
- Strong for store with 1000+ skus
- Strong for integration with legacy systems (major lift but refined to a really good structure)
- Will work with anything I throw it's way, from shipping integrations, payment providers, product structure, I'm pretty sure if I could dream it up it could be accomplished through code. However I did have 2-3 developers with capacity to work on my store anytime I wanted.
- Might be overkill for my current use case

**My use case**

- Will be running a store with 5-25 skus max
- Will be concentrating on checkout optimization. Basically I'm working for a new business that only sells a few core products. Think moving from amazon to dollarshaveclub
- The core business strategy shifts from discouvery of thousands of skus to learning about 3-5 core ones and buying as quick as possible.
- Limited development dollars - I suspect I will have 80hours dev time to launch the store. Then, I may have a part time dev on retainer for about 10 hours/week of work after launch.
- Any comments on built in CMS or Wordpress integrations?

I've also worked with hybris, and nopCommerce so have enough experience working with the biggest possible platform and lighter ones to be able to say I'm not interested any lighter platforms than these two.

My dev is proficient in both ruby on rails as well as php but has never worked on ecommerce specifically so thats where the learning will be.

Can anyone offer their experience?

Comment: I've worked with Magento and WordPress' WooCommerce platform. Out of the box I think Shopify is the easiest to use for my clients and for myself as the developer and I think their liquid setup is pretty good - files have built-in version control, though it does expire. I'm not a fan of their grid system though, but it gets the job done. Negatives, your pages and collections force the words in the URL strings (bad for SEO). Also, you have somewhat limited control of the final checkout page.

Comment: Thanks! Have you done any shipping integration? and have any of your clients expressed changes to the checkout page that would help their business that are not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what all the limitations are on the checkout page, but you can't even attempt to edit it until you're in the paid version (prior to that you won't even have the file). I have had clients make requests for this page too - one I'm currently working on wants an additional checkbox for when customers would like help with an installation - I'm waiting for them to go pro, but that shouldn't be too difficult to implement. It's worth noting that some apps all together change the checkout page to something of their own as well (i.e. BOLD Recurring Payments).